# Not understanding the definition of a differential of a map.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I'am reading Loring.W.Tu's book on Manifolds and I'am stuck at the point where he defines differential of a smooth map between smooth manifolds $N$ and $M$.

If $F:N\rightarrow M$ is a $C^{\infty}$ map between two manifolds (smooth) then at each point $p\in N$ it induces a linear map of tangent spaces
$$F_{*}:T_{p}N\rightarrow T_{F(p)}M$$as follows.If $X_{p}\in T_{p}N$ then $F_{*}(X_{p})$ is the tangent vector in $T_{F(p)}M$ defined by 
$$(F{*}(X_{p}))f=X_{p}(f\circ F) \in \mathbb{R}$$ for $f \in C^{\infty}_{F(p)}(M)$.

Can anyone help me out in decoding this and explain why this is a good generalisation of Jacobians.

Comment: This wiki article explains it quite nice https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_(differential)

Comment: This is 'generalization' of the Jacobian because in the special case where $N \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $M \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ are open subsets and $F$ is just a smooth map between them, the matrix associated with the linear map $F_{*}$ is given by the Jacobian matrix of $F$.

Comment: But I don't see how it follows from the above definition.

Comment: In the book there must have been a discussion of this simple case. If not, this is done in the chapter Tangent Vectors of John M. Lee's book Introduction to Smooth Manifolds, which can be found online.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The other answer covers it, but I think it is worthwhile to remark that the very definition of differential encodes how $(F_*)_p$ transforms tangent basis vectors, and so how it acts on $T_pN:$

if $p\in U\subseteq N$ and $(U,\phi)$ is a chart, then $\phi_*:T_pU\cong T_pM\to T_p \mathbb R^n$ is an isomorphism (because $\phi$ is a diffeomorphism) and so it makes sense to $\textit{define}$ for each $\ 1\le i\le n,\  \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}:=\phi^{-1}_*(\frac{\partial}{\partial r^i})$, where $r^i$ are the standard coordinates on $\mathbb R^n$. The same analysis applied to $F(p)\in V\subseteq M$ using the chart $(V,\psi)$ gives tangent vectors $\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}=\psi^{-1}_*(\frac{\partial}{\partial r^j})$ for $1\le j\le m$.

Then, a direct calculation shows that $(F_*)_p\left (\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\right )=\sum ^m_{j=1}\frac{\partial (\psi^j\circ F\circ \phi^{-1})}{\partial r^i}\cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}$.

The upshot of this is that the matrix of $F_*$ as a map from $T_pN$ to $T_{F(p)}M$ is precisely the Jacobian matrix of the function $\psi\circ F\circ \phi^{-1}$, which is a map between $\textit{Euclidean}$ spaces. And this result was ensured by the definitions.

Answer (score 3):

They talk about this in example 8.4. Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$ be smooth and $p\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Take standard coordinates of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$ via $(x^1,\cdots, x^n)$ and $(y^1\cdots, y^m)$, respectively. Then, the map $F_*:T_p\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow T_{F(p)}\mathbb{R}^m$ is a linear map. The entries of the matrix representation $[a_j^i]$ relative to the standard bases  (for the tangent spaces) is given via the formula $$F_*\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\Big|_p\right)=\sum\limits_k a_j^k\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\Big|_{F(p)}.$$ To determine the $a_j^i,$ simply evaluate both sides on $y^i$. The right will give you $a_j^i,$ and the left, by the definition of the pushforward, will  give you $\frac{\partial F^i}{\partial x^j}(p),$ where $F^i$ denote the coordinates of $F$ in the $y$ coordinate system. Hence, the matrix representation with respect to the bases $\{{\partial}/{\partial x^j}|_p\}$ and $\{{\partial}/{\partial y^j}|_{F(p)}\}$ is $[{\partial F^i}/{\partial x^j}(p)],$ which is the Jacobian that we all know and love.

So, this is a good generalization, since it matches what we should get in the Euclidean case.

Comment: Yes,I too saw the example but here they have assumed it to be linear(and linearity was given as excercise),how does the above statement be used to show that the differential is linear ?(The problem is that too many symbols somehow hides the simplicity ,so please help me out.)

Comment: Linearity is actually very easy. We need to show that if $F:N\rightarrow M$ is smooth, then $F_*(cX_p)=cF_*(X_p)$ and  $F_*(X_p+Y_p)=F_*(X_p)+F_*(Y_p)$ for any constant $c$ and $X_p, Y_p\in T_p N.$ To prove this is true, we need to prove that they give the same thing if we act on $f\in C_{F(p)}^\infty (M).$ Now, just use the definition and that tangent vectors are linear, by definition. The key is that, to show these sorts of things are true, we need to act  on an arbitrary $f\in C_{F(p)}^\infty (M)$. So, you just use the definition of the pushforward given by Tu.